# Is there a way to use SCSS to emulate previous sibling selection?

Tags: css, css-selectors, sass

I'm trying to learn more about creative ways to employ SCSS. I'm aware that one could potentially use jQuery to address this problem, but for the sake of separation of concerns, I'd like to avoid that route.

I have a fluid length list of elements (from 1 to 4 items long), one of which I will assign a class such as "primary". I'm using SCSS to generate selectors for the list length from 1 to 4, like so:

```
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}),
  li:first-child:nth-last-child(#{$i}) ~ li {
    width: 100% / #{$i}; 
      &.primary {
        transform: scale(1.35);
        background: red;
        z-index: #{$i};
      }
      &.primary + * {
        transform: scale(1.25);
        background: orange;
        z-index: #{$i - 1};
      }
      &.primary + * + * {
        transform: scale(1.15);
        background: yellow;
        z-index: #{$i - 2};
      }
  } 
}
```

Is there a way using **SCSS** (I know this is currently impossible with CSS) to select both the next and previous siblings of .primary in the list to get them to match?

See this [demo for reference](http://codepen.io/esjay/pen/irlIv). In this case, ITEM 2 is the .primary and ITEM 1 and ITEM 3 are previous and next siblings respectively.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### If you can assign class to parent instead

Cimmanon has given the correct answer as far as your parameters you mentioned. However, you do mention two factors that might make a possible solution:

1. You are dealing with a small subset of items (four at most).
2. You were planning on *assigning* a `primary` class to one item.

*If that class with an added number (like* `primary-1`*), can be assigned instead to the parent* `ol`, then you can generate css code that can get the selection capabilities that you want through *a single class assignment*. A sample css output would be like this ([**view fiddle example here of all variations**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvMDC/15/)):

```
.primary-1 > :nth-child(1),
.primary-2 > :nth-child(2),
.primary-3 > :nth-child(3),
.primary-4 > :nth-child(4) { 
   /* primary styles */   
}

.primary-1 > :nth-child(2),
.primary-2 > :nth-child(odd),
.primary-3 > :nth-child(even),
.primary-4 > :nth-child(3) { 
   /* immediately adjacent sibling styles */
}

.primary-1 > :nth-child(3),
.primary-2 > :nth-child(4),
.primary-3 > :nth-child(1),
.primary-4 > :nth-child(2) { 
   /* two removed sibling styles */
}

/* 3 removed sibling */
.primary-1 > :nth-child(4),
.primary-4 > :nth-child(1) { 
   /* three removed sibling styles */
}
```

Could SCSS help in building this? Probably, though because of the various combinations, not as easily as one might like.

Comment: I think you've struck the gist of what I was looking for. I'll see if I can improve readability using SCSS so it's obvious what is happening.

Thanks for the creative solution.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Because Sass is compiled into CSS, it has no knowledge of your document's DOM.  In order for Sass to be able to do what you're looking for, it would have to be a function of CSS.

Comment: Right, I get that it can't make magical CSS selectors. However, I was wondering about the combinatorics aspect of SCSS, such as the @for loop above combined with nth-child and nth-last-child to select lists of certain lengths.

Comment: Looping in Sass is just a convenience for us.  In the end, it still has to create valid CSS.

Comment: No argument here. But clean loops that can generate clever permutations seem interesting.

Comment: You have to have a CSS solution *first*.  Without it, there's no amount of looping that's going to help you.